# Rejecting requests to subdomains not explicitly configured

Tags: apache2, configuration, virtualhost

I am hosting a couple of site on my apache:

- domain-x.com
- domain-y.com
- test.domain-y.com

Each site has its own file in sites-available. Domain-y serves to sites, one with `domain-y.com` and the other with `test.domain-y.com`.

domain-x:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain-x.com
  Redirect permanent / https://domain-x.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost <ip>:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/<folder>
    ServerName domain-x.com
    ServerAlias "domain-x.com" "www.domain-x.com"
</VirtualHost>
```

domain-y:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain-y.com
  Redirect permanent / https://domain-y.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost <ip>:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/<folder>
    ServerName domain-y.com
    ServerAlias "domain-y.com" "www.domain-y.com"
</VirtualHost>
```

test.domain-y.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName test.domain-y.com
  Redirect permanent / https://test.domain-y.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost <ip>:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/<folder>
    ServerName test.domain-y.com
    ServerAlias "test.domain-y.com" "www.test.domain-y.com"
</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine but I would like to disable the test.domain-y.com if not needed and display a 404. If I remove the site using a2dissite and call the subdomain site "test.domain-y.com", the domain "domain-y.com" is shown instead without 404.

So I understood that I need a catch all, so I created a 00-catch.all.conf that holds these statements:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName null
 ServerAlias *
 Redirect 404 /
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
 ServerName null
 ServerAlias *
 Redirect 404 /
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName null
 ServerAlias *
 Redirect 404 /
</VirtualHost>
```

But if I enable the catch all then still the subdomain site is available.

Any hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you gonna have to make sure that catch-all is the last virtual host that Apache checks, if it is named `00-catch.all.conf` as you did it should be okay, then we have to check that your `catch-all` virtual host covers all the necessary ports, the 80 and 443 for `HTTP` and `HTTPS`, respectively.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName default
 ServerAlias *
 Redirect 404 /
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName default
 ServerAlias *
 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile "/etc/apache2/ssl/default.crt"
 SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/apache2/ssl/default.key"
 Redirect 404 /
</VirtualHost>
```

then I assume you have a default SSL certificate for your server to handle the HTTPS requests, replace `etc/apache2/ssl/default.crt` and `/etc/apache2/ssl/default.key` with it.

Comment: Hi, sorry that I could not answer earlier. I tried that but still, the disabled site is accessible.